# Does the United States Commission on International Religious Freedom work to prevent violation of or improve religious freedom in the US?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-religion

According to the official website of [United States Commission on International Religious Freedom (USCIRF)](https://www.uscirf.gov)

> USCIRF is an independent, bipartisan U.S. federal government commission, the first of its kind in the world, dedicated to defending the universal right to freedom of religion or belief abroad. USCIRF reviews the facts and circumstances of religious freedom violations and makes policy recommendations to the President, the Secretary of State, and Congress. USCIRF Commissioners are appointed by the President and the Congressional leadership of both political parties.

There have been events in the US like:

1. [Sikh owned restaurant vandalised in the US](https://m.freepressjournal.in/article/world/vandals-damage-indian-restaurant-in-usas-new-mexico-state-paint-the-walls-with-racist-graffiti/c15d422b-b907-4c1c-8238-8e8f7cdc982b) **June, 2020**
2. Poway synagogue shooting **2019**
3. Overland Park Jewish Community Center shooting **2014**
4. Wisconsin Sikh temple shooting **2012**
5. Pittsburgh synagogue shooting **2018**

**Question:** Since the USCIRF is bipartisan, did it make efforts in the past to prevent violations of religious freedom or improve religious tolerance in the US? Or does it look into internal matters?*(With the assumption that the US Government didn't tolerate the above mentioned events)*

Comment: How are your examples violations of religious freedom?  They do not seem to be in any way acts of government.  Quite the opposite, as IIRC they are actions of individual lunatics, with the government actively trying to hunt them down and arrest them.

Comment: `they are actions of individual lunatics, with the government actively trying to hunt them down and arrest them` Is this a reason why the Government of India rejected the USCIRF report on India?

Comment: I wouldn't know, since I have little knowledge of or interest in the government of India.

Comment: Electronically, no! Not sure in real life. Twitter advance search and press releases don't say anything about all those happenings. Not to insult anyone, but no one gives a damn anyway. Also, they are meant to analyse things abroad, which is their job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charter of USCIRF is directed towards non-US events (thus the "International" in its name) and does not have any domestic authority. The events you enumerate, being domestic would be handled by domestic law enforcement authorities, primarily at the local level, but involving the FBI if there is any federal law involved.

Comment: Why is the USCIRF bipartisan?

Comment: Many federal commissions are bipartisan by legislature since in theory their objectives shouldn't be partisan. In practice the commission will have an odd number of members with equal numbers of both parties plus one more member of the president's party.